# How I can to install media codec on fedora and watch video in browser?

Tags: linux, fedora

I am using fedora 31,and i can't watch online video in browser.Pleas help me to solve this problem. When I click watch video site answer` **html 5:Unsupported video format.Try to installing Flash Player**.

Comment: What browser?  Firefox?  Chrome?

Answer (score 2):

Fedora doesn't ship with many video codecs as many are considered proprietary and thus goes against their philosophy of open-sourced. You will have to add the [RPM Fusion](https://rpmfusion.org/Configuration) repo and download some of the more common video codecs.

Add RPM Fusion repo:

```
sudo dnf install https://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-$(rpm -E %fedora).noarch.rpm
```

Install ffmpeg:

```
sudo dnf install ffmpeg
```

After installing ffmpeg, it should pull everything necessary to play html5 videos.

Comment: actually it did it. remember to restart the browser

Comment: this worked for me on Fedora 36 beta (May 2022)